# Прошу помочь с редиректом

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache, маршрутизация

Прошу помощи в написании правильно редиректа.
Имеется сайт. В корне есть каталоги, например /cabinet/

Мне нужно, что бы при обращении http://site.ru/xxx - я бы брал этот xxx и использовал его в качестве параметра для запроса в БД и возвращал бы значение на его основе, но при этом чтобы у меня работал и адрес http://site.ru/cabinet/ - эта директория существует в корне сайта.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно такое сделать?
Используется Apache, mod_rewrite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужен ли здесь mod_rewrite ?
Напишите обычный роутер для path параметров
В Вашем случае если $patam == 'xxx' (условия сами формулируете регулярным выражением) то подключайте обработчик с запросом в БД.
Если $patam == 'cabinet' то без дополнительной обработки.
Проще будет управлять сайтом.
Может в неудачных терминах сформулировал, но смысла использовать mod_rewrite не вижу.
PS Если всё же очень нужно использовать mod_rewrite то нужно помнить, что по сути Вы напишете тот же самый роутер с регулярками, но средствами доступными для htaccess

Comment: Спасибо. Я так собственно и поступил. Добавил просто роутер.